# How to make sudo with POSIX shell better?

Tags: sudo, posix

I have made changes to my Arch Linux x86-64 system where I run bash exclusively through what I think is POSIX mode, through using `/bin/sh` (linked to '/bin/bash') as my login shell and instead of putting stuff in `/etc/profile` I defined `ENV=/etc/shrc` in my `/etc/environment` as per Bash manual, so that it executes the `/etc/shrc` file upon startup, where all my aliases, prompt and similar things go.

Basically, I wanted to completely abandon Bash specific features, including the `/etc/profile` and friends.

The problem has arisen though, where upon executing `sudo`, there is no `ENV` variable, as `sudo` apparantly reset environment (either after parsing `/etc/environment` or without do so at all) and thus all my aliases and things are gone. `sudo -i` does the same, basically - no `ENV`.

Should I consider this beneficial for system security, or should I do something about this, like make sudo preserve `ENV` variable?

To add to this grief, `su -` (but not `su`) also lacks `ENV` and thus all the stuff `/etc/shrc` does. So maybe this is not just `sudo` problem, after all? Bash manpage is not specific on this, I think - it merely says "When invoked as an interactive shell with the name sh, bash looks for variable ENV..." -Well, I **do** invoke it as interactive shell, don't I? Why is there no ENV in my environment (tested with `env`)

I don't understand how to preserve the POSIXness of it all and at the same time not introduce security weakness though making `sudo` preserve one or more env. variables. At least, it should preserve `ENV`, no?

I hope I am making myself clear here.

Comment: What platform is this? On some platforms "/bin/sh" links to [Almquist shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell).

Comment: Sorry, it's Arch Linux x86-64, I put it in the question.